# Android client and PHP server: common practice in communication

Tags: android, json, rest, soap, ksoap2

Good day!

I'm a web developer who has to choose a way\protocol for web-server (LAMP) <-> android app communication.

I personally prefer SOAP, but it seems that support of it on Android is bad. Android seems to have a Httpclient and I'm comfortable with JSON so we can go with plain POST requests with JSON data in and out.

REST is a modern word, is there something like SOAP/WSDL stuff but for JSON/plain Http request

Are there any proven Android-friendly solutions for client\server communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ksoap2-android project works just fine if you prefer SOAP. Otherwise you can look at gson or jackson or the json support in the sdk for REST support.

Comment: It seems that REST with JSON encoding is the most popular option now? At least it is more lightweight that SOAP.